# How can I move Eclipse RCP projects .pref files

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I've been looking for a way to do this and I'm seeing mixed info, [Lars Vogel's article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePreferences/article.html) suggests you can use the -Data program argument.

This moves the workspace, which is part of what I wanted, because I don't want my application to be writing any files to the run directory (it doesn't have access to do that) but it doesn't move my .pref files.

Most resources i'm seeing claim that the .pref files get stored in the workspace, but mine don't at all, they are under /configuration/.settings/ which is not in the workspace, but in the run directory of my exported exe.

Is there any way to get these preferences to go to the user home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The majority of preferences are in the workspace (these are 'InstanceScope' preferences)

There are a few which are global to all workspaces which are stored in the /configuration/.settings location (mostly to do with the recent workspaces values) - these are 'ConfigurationScope' preferences.

The 'multi-user install' support does allow some changes to be made to locations - see [Eclipse multi-user installs](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fmulti_user_installs.html) in the help